# How to run multiple queries simultaneously?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Can I run more than one query at a time in Oracle Developer?

In SQL SERVER, I can have multiple queries written out, hit F5, and SQL Server will run them one at a time - with multiple results tables, one for each query.

I have about 200 select statements - basically, just want to find out which columns in which tables contain a certain phrase.

So far, I've just listed all the queries and have been ctrl+entering them one by one - which is absurd.  Not sure how to wrap them.

For example, i have about 200 of these:

```
select [PRIO_DESCRIPTION] from IPTELMGR.VW_JOB_QUEUE where PRIO_DESCRIPTION like '%Waiting for Prot out work order to be closed.%'
select [PRIO_DESCRIPTION] from IPTELMGR.TMP$$$_JOB_TERMINATE where PRIO_DESCRIPTION like '%Waiting for Prot out work order to be closed.%'
select [LONG_DESC] from IPTELMGR.ENTITY_LOOKUPS_LOG where LONG_DESC like '%Waiting for Prot out work order to be closed.%'
```

Hoping to find a format where I can just run these all at once, and which ever result returns something other than "missing expression" will lead me in the right direction.

(i know this is the wrong way to go about it, but really just want to figure multiple queries out before trying the right approach.)

Comment: Is the missing `from` a typo or some new feature ?

Comment: Try after adding semicolon ; after each script. It should solve your issue.

Comment: @JorgeCampos haha sorry about that, i didn't miss it in the actual application though..

also, still same question

Comment: @mkRabbani looks like that was my issue!  i guess that's a difference between sql server and oracle developer...thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In SQL SERVER, I can have multiple queries written out, hit F5, and
>   SQL Server will run them one at a time - with multiple results tables,
>   one for each query.

Ok, well, I think you mean you want to in, one go, kick off execution of every query and get results back...not actually run all 200 concurrently.

You have two options. You can also just hit F5 (or use the button I outlined in red), and we'll run all of those and you'll see the output below in a script panel

[image]

OR

You can select all and then ctrl+enter, and we'll do exactly what SSMS did, or you described above, each result set will get a data grid

[image]